# NestedClass need some explaination

Tags: java

i have this code but i dont understand it at all , i dont understand why one of its vaues return to value that was initialized at first ,and the other one continues where it was left;

The code:

```
public class Out{

private int value = 1;

public In initBrenda(String emri) {
    return new Brenda(emri);
}

protected class In{

    private int value = 10;
    private String name;

    public Brenda(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public void printIn() {
        System.out.println(name+ ": value= " + value++);
    }

    public void printOut() {
        System.out.println(name+ ": out value = " + Out.this.value++);
    }
}
```

}

Test Class:

```
public class OutTest{

public static void main(String[] arg) {
    Out j = new Out();
    Out.In b = j.initBrenda("111");        
    b.printIn();
    b.printIn();
    b.printOut();
    b.printOut();

    System.out.println("=======");
    Out.In b1 = j.new In("222");
    b1.printIn();
    b1.printIn();
    b1.printOut();
    b1.printOut();
}
```

}

```
111: value= 10
111: value = 11
111: value out= 1
111: value out = 2
=======
222: value = 10
222: value = 11
222: value out = 3
222: value out = 4
```

My question is why out is not reseting to 1 , and to start counting again!!
Thank you!!

Comment: I don't think the code above compiles.  Copy/paste error?  Where is this ctor? `Out.In b1 = j.new In("222");`

Comment: Have you mistaken `In` for `Brenda`?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why out is not reseting to 1 , and to start counting again!

Why should it? You refer here to the `value` field of `Out`, which have one instance `j` in your code.

When you create a new instance of `In` (`j.new In("222");`), you only create a new instance of `In` for the same instance `j` of `Out`. No new instance of `Out` is created here.

So the `Out.value` is not reset because nothing resets it.